# Bosonic coherent state normalization

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In the paper [arXiv:1208.3469](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.3469) (equation (85)) it is stated that the coherent state for two bosons with corresponding annihilation operators $a,b$ can be written as:

$$|\Psi_\lambda \rangle = \sqrt{1-|\lambda|^2} e^{-\lambda a^\dagger b^\dagger}|0\rangle,$$

where $|0\rangle$ is the vacuum.

I tried to check that this state is indeed normalised and tried to derive equation (86) in the paper but failed. My attempt is the following:

\begin{align}
\langle \Psi_\lambda |\Psi_\lambda \rangle 
& = (1-|\lambda|^2)\langle 0|e^{-\lambda^\star ab} e^{-\lambda a^\dagger b^\dagger}|0\rangle
\\ &  = (1-|\lambda|)^2 \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty \langle 0|a^n (a^\dagger)^m b^m (b^\dagger)^n |0\rangle (-\lambda)^n (-\lambda^\star)^m.
\end{align}

Then we see that only cases with $m=n$ survive and that each term simply gives $(n!)^2$ since e.g. $\langle 0|a^n (a^\dagger)^n|0\rangle = n!$.

What is wrong in my reasoning here?

Comment: Please [link to abstract pages instead of directly to pdfs](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11400/what-is-the-policy-for-linking-e-g-why-should-we-link-to-abstract-pages-rathe).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thank you for the remark. I will do it in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a factor of $1/n!$ in your exponential expansions, and then forgot to use the geometric series. The correct set of steps are:
$$\langle \Psi_\lambda |\Psi_\lambda \rangle = (1-|\lambda|^2)\langle 0|e^{-\lambda^\star ab} e^{-\lambda a^\dagger b^\dagger}|0\rangle = (1-|\lambda|)^2 \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty \frac{\langle 0|a^n (a^\dagger)^m b^m (b^\dagger)^n |0\rangle}{n! m!} (-\lambda)^n (-\lambda^\star)^m.$$
And then as you point out, the expectation values are $\frac{\langle 0|a^n (a^\dagger)^m b^m (b^\dagger)^n |0\rangle} = \delta_{mn} n! m!$, and from there you get
$$
\cdots = (1-|\lambda|)^2 \sum_{m,n=0}^\infty |\lambda|^{2n} = 1.
$$
where the geometric series says that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}$ for $r$ in the unit ball.